# Reproduce solr LockObtainFailed error issue in lower environment

Tags: kubernetes, solr

We have been trying to reproduce the **LockObtainFailed** error in a lower environment as it happens in production. This is the setup we have in production: One solr-master, two solr-slave pods running in Kubernetes with PersistentVolumeClaims to store the index.

We have written a script to delete write.lock file every 5 mins in production to resolve this issue temporarily. But the issue happens intermittently and updates/ deletes to solr goes missing now and then. Is there a permanent solution? We have read many online forums and stack overflow questions/answers which suggest changing **lock type** from 'Native' to 'Simple' and increase **writelocktimeout** from 1 second to 60 seconds.

We are trying to reproduce this issue in a lower environment (Kubernetes) then apply this fix to see if this configuration will fix the issue before applying this fix in production. We are at this issue for months. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do each pod have their own volume claim, or is there one single claim that is mounted as ReadWriteMany for multiple pods?

Comment: Yes, we have separate PVC for each pod, and it's mounted as ReadWriteOnce